# Problem with downloading utf-8 encoded csv file using Spring boot and HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, utf-8, byte-order-mark

I needed to create and download a *utf-8* encoded csv file in my spring boot application. 
The problem is that *Excel 2019* is unable to open it correctly and as you may guess all those utf-8 characters are shown as strange symbols. I read somewhere that adding *BOM* characters to the start of csv file would solve the problem. I did it manually and it works actually. But, when I use the *HttpServletResponse* as follows it doesn't work:

```
HttpServletResponse response = ...;//coming from rest api call
response.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/csv; charset=UTF-8");
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

/*write o response file csvWriter and flush/close it*/
try {
    ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
    outputStream.write(new byte[]{239, 187, 191});//add utf-8 BOM bytes
    outputStream.write("some,utf8,text".getBytes());
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle exception
}
```

I checked the generated *test.csv* file with some *HEX* viewer tool to see if there are those *BOM* bytes at the start of file. Very strangely they weren't there. Although I explicitly write them to the file, they are haven't been written at the start of file. very very stragne. 
Can anybody help?!

Comment: Why don't you try outputStream.print instead? Not sure if write of BOM characters would start from first byte and clear the response.getOutputStream()...

Comment: @JGFMK I tried print method too but got the same behaviour. This become more strange when I write some ascii character like 'H' before writting those BOM bytes.  In this case, I can see them in HEX viewer at the exact order that I wrote them.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and find the solution by using the header of CSV Format :

```
CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(httpServletResponse.getWriter(), CSVFormat.EXCEL.withHeader("\ufeff");
```

We can still add others strings in header after the byte order mark, it still works.